# unable to assign string value having white space to display property in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am having following code that works absolutely fine in chrome but when run on IE 11, I am not able to assign value `" block "` to display css property.
I have fix the issue by trimming string to `"block"`.
But I am not able to understand the difference between the code processing of chrome and IE(11).
Below is my code :

```
var bStr = " block "; Element.style.display = 1 == 0 ? "none" : bStr;
```

This gives me `Element.style.display = "none";`

It gives me `Element.style.display = "none";` when I assign `bstr = "block";`
Please share your views. Thanks!

Comment: In your ternary statement, 1 will never == 0, so it will always assign `display` to `none`

Comment: @user184994 `1 == 0 ? "none" : bStr;` will give you bStr because 1==0 will give you false.

Comment: Oops, ignore me, of course...

Comment: Well from your own description it sounds like IE11 doesn't like spaces in the display property, what's there not to understand, Chrome is just a better browser than IE11?.  Why do you want spaces anyway?.

Comment: yeah sure chrome is better. dint want spaces, came from database so had dealt with it. thanks!